# Launch Android activity when click on href in Chrome browser

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want to open my app's LoginActivity when click on a `<a href="www.myhost.com"/>` in some web in Chrome browser app. I have this code but it is not working:

```
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask"
                          android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">  
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
          <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost.com"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it up like this :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Notice that in your case, you would need to use android:pathPrefix instead of android:path.